# Gunicorn around 100% CPU usage

Tags: linux, webserver, gunicorn

Sometimes my web server just stops responding.

What I found out is that at these moments Gunicorn processes' CPU load is around 100%. I have not changed codebase in a while so I don't think it might cause that.

Here's the bash script I use to run gunicorn:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /etc/profile.d/myapp.sh

NAME="myapp-web-services"
DJANGODIR="/home/myapp/myapp-web-services"
SOCKFILE=/tmp/myapp-web-services.sock
USER=myapp
GROUP=myapp
NUM_WORKERS=9
TIMEOUT=100
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=settings.wsgi

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

cd $DJANGODIR
source /home/myapp/.virtualenvs/myapp-web-services/bin/activate
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec newrelic-admin run-program /home/myapp/.virtualenvs/myapp-web-services/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=warning \
  --timeout=$TIMEOUT \
  --log-file=- \
  --max-requests=1200
```

I have 4 CPUs in the system so according to documentation 9 workers should be fine.